# replacing AxMSComCtl2.AxAnimation with a .net equivalent

Tags: activex

I have a legacy implementation that I am upgrading from VS 2008 to VS 2010.
Embedded in the application is an animation using AxMSComCtl2.AxAnimation.  when I try to view the form, I get a   Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG) for the AxAmimation.

This is a trivial animation that works under VS 2008 executibles that shows stuff moving from one place to another.   It is not required for the application to work correctly.

I would love to get rid of the ActiveX stuff and replace it with a .net equivalent, but I haven't been able to find documentation on the AX animation or on .net equivalents.   I would gladly just eliminate it if I cannot replace it.

Comment: It is an olden VB6 control, time has not been kind to it.  It does very little, just plays back a video in the AVI format.  Usually the "flying folder" animation when you copy files, it makes your app look like it hasn't been maintained for 20 years.  Just kill it, a ProgressBar in marquee mode will do.  If you want the modern animated copy progress window then consider the FileSystem.CopyDirectory() method.

Comment: Thanks - I will take a look.   Killing it got me up and running.